# How can I remove module name from module list in Layout

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have added one custom module in OpenCart 2. but, **I want to remove module name from module list in admin Layout page.**

is it possible?

(admin > System > Design > Layouts) 
[image]

Comment: You have to customize the controller file `layout.php`. Because opencart lists all the modules in layout form which have code `module`. `$extensions = $this->model_extension_extension->getInstalled('module');`

Comment: You have to move that module to a different folder and change the class name accordingly. The `admin/controller/module` folder is strictly designed for modules, that could be added to specific layouts.

Comment: @TiborB. What if it's an admin side module?

Comment: Change the custom module type i.e. from module to `module` to `customname` in extension table.